# Probability Question - Mp3 player chooses songs

Tags: probability

A mp3 player contains 10 different songs in its memory and chooses songs randomly (every choice is independent on the previous choices).

Let X be the number of songs one will hear until the first time (including this time) the same song will be chosen twice in a row .

A. Write the probability function of X

B. What is the expectation of X?

My attempt:
I am not quite sure, but this is what I thought:
First , $max(X)= 10 $ . So all I need is to calculate the probability $p$ of choosing the same song twice in a row and then in A, $P(X=k)=Geometric(p)$ .

Is the following calculation correct? 
$$
P(X=k)= \frac{9\cdot 8 \cdot ...\cdot (9-k+2) }{10^k} 
$$

But how can I relate this to a geometric distribution that will allow me to calculate part B ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: Birthday Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of ways to list $10$ different songs $k$ times, where in the first $k-2$ songs no $2$ consecutive songs are identical and the last $2$ songs are identical, is equal to the product of:

- $10$ options for song  $\#1$
- $ 9$ options for songs $\#2,\dots,\#k-1$
- $ 1$ option  for songs $\#k$

The total number of ways to list $10$ different songs $k$ times is $10^k$.

Hence the probability function is:

$$P(X=k)=\frac{10\cdot9^{k-2}\cdot1}{10^k}=\frac{9^{k-2}}{10^{k-1}}$$

Comment: I agree with your denominator. As for the numerator: 

I do not think you have 9 options for songs #2,...#k-1 , because once you are not allowed to choose two identical songs consecutively .  i.e. - You indeed have 10 options for the song that will be played twice in a row, but as for the previous ones- you have $9\cdot 8 \cdot 7 ... $ 

Am I right ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: @CrazyStatistician: Wrong. Your description here implies that you cannot have, for example, a list of songs $4,5,4,5,4,5,5$, although there are no $2$ consecutive identical songs in that list until the last $2$ songs.

Comment: OK  you are right ! Thanks ! I think I got it!

Comment: @CrazyStatistician: Well, because that might lead to $2$ identical songs at the beginning. You seem to be confusing the **id** of the songs with the number of songs that you're allowed to choose from at each point. I suggest that you refer to the songs by letters instead. So for example, suppose that your songs are labeled A thru J. First song can be any of those $10$ options. Second song can be any of those $10$ options except for the one that you have previously chosen. Same goes for every other song, until the last one, which **has to be** identical to the one before it.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot ! 
One last thing - the only way to calculate the expectation in the way you suggested is to sum up:
$ \Sigma k\cdot P(X=k)  $?

Comment: @CrazyStatistician: As is the case when calculation the expectancy in any other question out there (simply because that's **the definition of expectancy**).

Comment: Great. Thanks !!!!!

Comment: @CrazyStatistician: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

The random variable $Y=X-1$ will be geometric with parameter $0.1$.  (You can't get a match on the first song; but after that, the probability of a match with the immediately previous song is $0.1$ on each trial.)

So $P(X=x) = 0.9^{x-2}\cdot 0.1$ for $X = 2, 3, 4, \dots$

And $E[X]=1+E[Y]=1+\frac{1}{0.1}=1+10=11$

Comment: $P>1$??? You gotta be missing parenthesis there or something (or maybe it should be a minus sign)...

Comment: @Barak Manos: Ouch.  You're right.  Thanks.  Fixed, I think.

Comment: I got $0.9^{x-2}\cdot0.1^{k-1}$, so at least one of us is wrong I suppose (BTW, I calculated the same expectancy "offline", which makes it really weird now).

Comment: Will you please explain how did you calculate the probability of a match with the immediately previous song  ? 

Thanks

Comment: @Barak Manos: You only need one match, so I think you only need one factor of $0.1$.  I may be misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: @CrazyStatistician: There are $10$ differnt songs.  On any given trial (after the first trial) you are seeing if you matched the one (immediately) previous song.  The probability of this is $\frac{1}{10}$--the mp3 player is choosing one song out of ten.  This holds for each trial starting with the second trial.  (Trial = a song randomly selected and played by mp3 player.)

Comment: I calculated the number of ways to make such list of length $k$, divided by the total number of ways to make **any** list of length $k$.

Comment: Sorry, we're both correct. The term $0.9^{k-2}$ already "embeds the other power". I used $9^{k-2}$ in my answer, and hence my silly misunderstanding of your answer. They are identical!